# How to concatenate variable in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules, custom-post-type

I want to know how can I concatenate **[und][0][value]**. 
I don't want to write every time [und][0][value]. So I have do like this:

```
   <?php

   $und_value = $load->field_testimonial_location['und'][0]['value'];

   $query = db_select('node','n');
   $query->fields('n',array('nid'));
   $query->condition('n.type','testimonial','=');
   $result = $testimonial_query->execute();

   while($fetch = $result->fetchObject()){

    $load = node_load($fetch->nid);
    // $location = $load->field_testimonial_location['und'][0]['value']; 
    $location = $load->field_testimonial_location.$und_value;
    echo $location;
   }
```

But its not working. It outputs **Array Array** So have any idia for this problem? How can I do?  [Full code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whBOl.png)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make some function which will take node field as parameter and return it's value

```
function field_value($field){
  return $field['und'][0]['value'];
}
```

Something like that (not tested).

But if you don't want to use function try using curly braces like:

```
$location = $load->{field_testimonial_location.$und_value};
```

That should work...

Comment: Just be aware, for some field types last arey level key is not always "value". Sometime it's "nid" or "tid" (for nod/taxonomy term references), sometime it's "uri"...for images and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Extending answer posted by MilanG, to make function more generic

`function field_value($field, $index = 0 ){
  return $field['und'][$index]['value'];
}`

There are time when you have multi value fields, in that case you have to pass index of the value also. For example

`$field['und'][3]['value'];`

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use such abbreviations, they will not suit all cases and eventually break your code.

Instead, there is already a tool do create custom code with easier syntax: [Entity Metadata Wrapper](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/entity-metadata-wrappers).

Basically, instead of

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$field_value = $node->field_name['und'][0]['value'];
```

you can then do something like

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
$field_value = $node_wrapper->field_name->value();
```

With the node wrapper you can also set values of a node, it's way easier and even works in multilingual environments, no need to get the language first (`$node->language`) or use constants (`LANGUAGE_NONE`).

In my custom module, I often use `$node` for the node object and `$enode` for the wrapper object. It's equally short and still know which object I am working on.